# Plotting of Production of PV, Demand Load, and Battery Generation

Tags: python, plot

So I want to fill this area, but it's still fill the area that I do not want. *blue line is the area I only wanted to fill.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9N0n.png)

I tried to code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def plot_dispatch(pv, beban, E, target_date):
    
    from datetime import datetime
    target_datetime = datetime.strptime(target_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    sliced_index = (pv.index.date == target_datetime.date())
    pv_sliced = pv[sliced_index]
    beban_sliced = beban[sliced_index]
    self_consumption = E['inv_load'][sliced_index]
    pv_load_sliced = E['pv_load'][sliced_index]
    res_pv_sliced = E['res_pv'][sliced_index]
    grid_load_sliced = E['grid_load'][sliced_index]
    batt_load_sliced = E['batt_load'][sliced_index]
    pcs_batt_sliced = E['pcs_batt'][sliced_index]
    cha_cap_sliced = E['cha_cap'][sliced_index]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(15, 4), frameon=False)

    axes.plot(pv_sliced.index, beban_sliced, label='Beban', color='black', lw=2)
    axes.fill_between(self_consumption.index, 0, self_consumption, label='Self Consumption', color='orange', alpha=.5)
    
    axes.fill_between(pv_sliced.index, beban_sliced, pv_sliced, label='Excess PV', color='green', alpha=.5)
    
    axes.fill_between(res_pv_sliced.index, self_consumption, pv_sliced, label='Konsumsi Panel Surya', color='yellow', alpha=.5)
    axes.fill_between(batt_load_sliced.index, pv_sliced, batt_load_sliced + pv_sliced, label='Konsumsi Baterai', color='blue', alpha=.5, hatch='//')
    axes.fill_between(grid_load_sliced.index, pv_sliced + batt_load_sliced, grid_load_sliced + pv_sliced + batt_load_sliced, 
                     label='Pembelian Jaringan PLN', color='grey', alpha=.2)
    axes.plot(grid_load_sliced.index, grid_load_sliced, color='red', label='Pemangkasan Jaringan PLN', ls=":", lw=1)
    axes.set_ylim([0, axes.get_ylim()[1]])
    axes.set_ylabel('Daya (kW)')
    
    axes.legend(loc='upper left')
    
    time_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(time_format)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.xlabel('Waktu')

    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=0.9, left=0.1, right=0.9, hspace=0.4)
    
    plt.show()

    return
```

Now think that I miss replaced in this line:

```
axes.fill_between(pv_sliced.index, beban_sliced, pv_sliced, label='Excess PV', color='green', alpha=.5)
```

Can anybody help me?